# How can you convert an NSImage to an NSMutable Array in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsimage

I have an NSImage which I need to convert to an NSMutable Array of the same size.

I originally converted an NSMutableArray to NSImage, resized, converted to CVPixelBuffer, and fed into a coreML model.

```
NSSize newSize;
newSize.height = 512;
newSize.width = 512;

const NSImage* segImage = [Viewer1.imageView nsimage:YES];
[segImage setScalesWhenResized:YES]; //'setScalesWhenResized:' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6

NSImage *resized = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: newSize];
[resized lockFocus];
[segImage setSize: newSize];
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation: NSImageInterpolationHigh];
[segImage drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
[resized unlockFocus];
```

The model produced a CVPixelBuffer which I converted to CGImageRef, then to NSImage which I resized (maybe there's a less convoluted way of doing all this?).

```
//Convert to NSImage and Resize
NSSize oldSize;
oldSize.height = pixHeight;
oldSize.width = pixWidth;

//const NSImage* segImage2 = [Viewer1.imageView nsimage:YES];
[newImage setScalesWhenResized:YES]; //'setScalesWhenResized:' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.6

NSImage *ROImask = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: oldSize];
[ROImask lockFocus];
[newImage setSize: oldSize];
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation: NSImageInterpolationHigh];
[newImage drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, oldSize.width, oldSize.height) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
[ROImask unlockFocus];
```

Now I just need to come full circle and convert the NSImage back to an NSMutableArray. How is this done in Objective C?

Comment: What do you expect the `NSMutableArray` to *contain*?

Comment: It should just be pixel values (probably floats) in the same dimensions as the original NSMutableArray (240x256). The original NSMutable array is pixel values from the Osirix viewer.